# Wiremock not matching regex

Tags: regex, mocking, url-pattern, wiremock

I'm using wiremock to mock certain requests and their respective response, but I'm trying to add a regex. Unfortunately, this just throws an exception stating that the request was not matched.

```
{
  "request" : {
     "method": "GET",
     "urlPattern": "/my/service/url?^.*(specificParam.*(M[0-9]{9})).*$"
   },
 "response": {
   ...
   }
}
```

I also tried it with

```
"urlPattern": "/my/service/url\\?^.*(specificParam.*(M[0-9]{9})).*$"
```

The request I'm sending is 
`/my/service/url?saml2=disabled&filter=specificParam%20eq%20%27M012345678%27`

Does anyone have an idea why the request is not being matched to the mapping?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try this :

```
{
  "request" : {
     "method": "GET",
     "urlPattern": "^\/my\/service\/url\\?.*(specificParam.*(M[0-9]{9})).*$"
   },
   "response": {
   ...
   }
}
```

See this regex here : https://regex101.com/r/B3XACf/1

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks! I should've put the ^ at the beginning of the urlPattern