# Wiremock JSON - Parameter Patterns

Tags: unit-testing, url, wiremock

I have this url:

```
 "url": "/application/userId=5678"
```

This url will contains the logged in userId, i am trying to map this userId with regex to be mapped on all url's in Wiremock Testing.

So far, i've tried this

```
"urlPattern": "/application/userId=[0-9]+"
```

But this is not working, any idea how to make this url work for any UserId?

Comment: Was it your intention for userId=5678 to be part of the path?

Or should it have been `/application?userId=5678` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx should be something like:
`^\/application\/userId=[0-9]+$`

See also this question + answer:
[Wiremock not matching regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085155/wiremock-not-matching-regex/51086629#51086629)